# Gtk.Image is not displayed

Tags: icons, application-development, pygtk

i am having a problem with a `Gtk.Image`. I use the `set_from_file()` function to add the image to the `Gtk.Image` but the image is not displayed! Instead the broken icon is.

The image exists and I can open it with the default image viewer so its not corrupted.

I tried with `Pixbuf` also but I get the same result.

Any idea why the image appears corrupted and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken icon means that there is a problem with the path of the image you are trying to set.Your code is correct. It just can't find the image you want to use thus a broken image is displayed instead.

```
 image = gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_file("/home/your_username/path/to/your/image.png")
```

In order to prevent mistakes from wrong paths, I suggest browsing with Nautilus at the image you want to use, right click on it -> *Properties* - > *Basic : Location*

Comment: But the image exist, example: the image must be `/tmp/tmplMJf2g/The_Breaker_NW_c77[a-team].cbr/The_Breaker_NW77_001.png` so i cd into the folder 

`chris@chris-Aspire-5732Z:~$ cd /tmp/tmplMJf2g/The_Breaker_NW_c77[a-team].cbr/
chris@chris-Aspire-5732Z:/tmp/tmplMJf2g/The_Breaker_NW_c77[a-team].cbr$ ls
The_Breaker_NW77_001.png` as you can see the image exist...

Comment: The image MAY exist but the path for the image you are writing is wrong.Where is that image anyway?Why don't you move it to the Desktop or something like that and use /home/user/Desktop/image.png ? that would make your life a lot easier

Comment: i download the image to /tmp for short-life use and then its deleted, thats why i save it to /tmp...Any other idea? except changing folder...can i use something else to display an image?

Comment: I told you that the problem is the path....the name of the file may be wrong.